# php-soap 5.3.17-2 el6 x86_64

Tags: linux, yum, centos6, rpm, soap

I just transferred a website to a server where I appear to lack the PHP-SOAP extension.

Unfortunately I cannot upgrade to the 5.4.10 that is available on remi at the moment as I am not 100% sure if the existing codes would still work and not cause any issues.

All websites are built without notices and anything so if any function would trigger a deprecated notice it would break the code.

I have been searching for the php-soap-5.3.17-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm package on Google for most of today and still cannot find it or any other that would be compatible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this is from Scientific Linux's repo:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ yum info php-soap-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security
Installed Packages
Name        : php-soap
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.3.3
Release     : 14.el6_3
Size        : 324 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : sl-security
Summary     : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
URL         : http://www.php.net/
License     : PHP
Description : The php-soap package contains a dynamic shared object that will add
            : support to PHP for using the SOAP web services protocol.

[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

Comment: I need 5.3.17-2.

Comment: did you try build it yourself? does 5.4.0 requires 5.3.17+ or is 5.3.3 is sufficent?

Comment: I do not want to upgrade to 5.4.10. I currently have 5.3.17-2 and I need the php-soap-5.3.17-2 package. I have tried 5.3.19 but it will not work with 5.3.17.

Comment: sorry, then .. keep on looking or see if you can build that RPM yourself

Comment: I asked Remi for the rpm and he was very nice to provide it. I tried to find the soap sources to build it but it proved to be a challenge as soap is not very popular plus Pear has released a version of their own.